# ¿Cómo lograr un espaciado entre los CheckBox?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, checkbox

Tengo un `div` el cual contiene varios `checbox` y quisiera poder separarlos unos de otros un poco más, pues están muy pegados.

Este es mi código:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="sun" data-field="Sun">
    Sun
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="mon" data-field="Mon" style="padding:10px;">
    Mon
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="tue" data-field="Tue">
    Tue
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="wed" data-field="Wed">
    Wed
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="thu" data-field="Thu">
    Thu
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="fri" data-field="Fri">
    Fri
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="sat" data-field="Sat">
    Sat
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Estas usando Bootstrap?

Comment: Si estoy usando bootstrap amigo

Comment: ¿Qué versión? Edita la pregunta agregando estos datos, es muy importante..

Comment: Si alguna respuesta pudo resolver el problema puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 1):

solo sleccionalos directamnete desde css y dale un `margin` a tu gusto

```css
input[type=checkbox]{

   margin:10px !important;
   

}
```

```html
div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="sun" data-field="Sun">
                            Sun
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="mon" data-field="Mon" style="padding:10px;">
                            Mon
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="tue" data-field="Tue">
                            Tue
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="wed" data-field="Wed">
                            Wed
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="thu" data-field="Thu">
                            Thu
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="fri" data-field="Fri">
                            Fri
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="sat" data-field="Sat">
                            Sat
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: lo hice asi pero al parecer una clase css llamada minimal me esta afectando y no deja hacer el espaciado

Comment: agrega !important al codigo css que te puse mira la edition te tiene que funcionar si o si con important

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo que puedes hacer es agregar la propiedad `margin-right` a tus `label` y agregarle todo el espaciado que desees. Yo agregue una clase llamada `.add-margin` a la etiqueta `head`, y luego agregue dicha clase a todos los `label`, así se te hará más cómodo probar el margen que deseas

```css
.add-margin {
    margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="add-margin">
          <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="sun" data-field="Sun">
          Sun
        </label>
        <label class="add-margin">
          <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="mon" data-field="Mon" style="padding:10px;">
          Mon
        </label>
        <label class="add-margin">
          <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="tue" data-field="Tue">
          Tue
        </label>
        <label class="add-margin">
          <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="wed" data-field="Wed">
          Wed
        </label class="add-margin">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="thu" data-field="Thu">
          Thu
        </label class="add-margin">
        <label class="add-margin">
          <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="fri" data-field="Fri">
          Fri
        </label>
        <label class="add-margin">
          <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="sat" data-field="Sat">
          Sat
        </label>
      </div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo mer funciono esta variante, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Porque no utilizas `margin-left` asi:

```css
.minimal {
    margin-left:40px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="sun" data-field="Sun">
                            Sun
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="mon" data-field="Mon" style="padding:10px;">
                            Mon
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="tue" data-field="Tue">
                            Tue
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="wed" data-field="Wed">
                            Wed
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="thu" data-field="Thu">
                            Thu
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="fri" data-field="Fri">
                            Fri
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="minimal form-control" name="sat" data-field="Sat">
                            Sat
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: amigo minimal es una clase que viene de icheck y no deberia cambiar esa clase propia de el, deberia hacerlo sin tocar esa clase, para no afectar en otros lugares que se hace uso de la misma, cuando lo hago desde otra clase no me funciona

Comment: Puedes agregar otra clase, o incluir el cambio solo en el archivo que necesitas.

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono poniendole la clase al label